# Can't get Javascript code to work in custom Firefox toolbar extension

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, toolbar, xul

I am learning to create a toolbar extension in Firefox using this [tutorial](https://www.borngeek.com/firefox/toolbar-tutorial/). So far so good, until I got to [*Chapter 6: Scripting the Toobar*](https://www.borngeek.com/firefox/toolbar-tutorial/chapter-6/). In the section *Adding Functionality to the Buttons*, I completed the first part (Javascript Revision 1) but when I went to Firefox, the script didn't work. None of the buttons work at all. I read back through a few times to make sure I typed the code into the XUL and JS files correctly, but nothing changed. I'm not sure if it's the problem with the code, with Firefox's settings or if my computer is somehow preventing it from working. What went wrong here?

Note: Javascript in html of other projects work fine on this computer. For this toolbar extension, however, I'm using a brand new developer profile with brand new default settings except what the tutorial asked me to change.

Comment: Without code, a [mcve], this question may be off-topic: : Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include: •the desired behavior, •a specific problem or error *and* •the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: *How to create a [mcve], [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I recommend that if you are just starting to learn to [write extensions for Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons), you do *not* start learning Overlay or Restartless extensions, unless you *need* to (If you don't *know* you need to, then you almost certainly don't). You should use the [Add-on SDK](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK). [WebExtensions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions) would be better, if you know what to expect working with alpha quality software interfaces (it is in development, but is really not ready for general use yet).

Comment: @Makyen downloading software is not possible, that's why I used this method since I can do everything by hand. I used the exact identical code as what's in the tutorial, so I didn't feel a need to quote what's already cited. Everything prior to adding the js code works, so I don't think the issue is there. I checked through the js code. I'm pretty sure it's not a typo, since ALL the js functionality isn't working.

Comment: I'm not sure what is the problem, so idk what info is useful to you. If you can ask some questions, I should be able to tell you what you need to know

Comment: I would second @Makyen and strongly suggest to look at Add-on SDK. The XUL based addon api is going to expire soon.